# password lock using I2c lcd and 4x4 matrix keypad on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create a door lock using the raspberry pi that interfaces a 4x4 matrix keypad and an I2C lcd display. I've wired the 4x4 matrix and the lcd display on a breadboard and managed to get python codes to make them work individually.

The issue I'm having now is combining the codes in such a way that the lcd display shows enter password and once the correct password is entered, it displays "accepted" and a led turns on to indicate password correct. I also want to include a buzzer that buzzes when the password is wrong.